# Stopping user from making in app purchases on a live iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I am trying to stop user from making in app purchases on a live iPhone app. What i have done is i made  Cleared for Sale: No in itunesconnect product id and Status is changed to 
Status: Developer Removed from Sale. But still i am able to do in app purchase in the app. Any idea why is it? anything i should do? i don't want to delete the product id from the itunesconnect

http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/8365/82a8.png

Thanks

Comment: did you reset your app, device & account after removing item from the sale

Comment: The store is in the cloud. You have to wait for it to propagate.

Comment: yea, i tried that, i even deleted the app and re installed. But no luck..

Comment: How much time it will take to update, its been more than 48hrs over, Still i am able to purchase the items.